# Calling an event just once in a for loop

Tags: javascript

been trying to tackle this problem for a couple of hours, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Basically, I have an Audio player, using HTML5.
There is an event listener while the audio is playing, which fires every second until the audio is finished.

I generate markers on the audio timeline based on the timestamp given by the API, it looks like this.

[image]

There are three markers placed here - If the total duration was 60 seconds, the markers would be at 5, 10, 29 I suppose.

After each marker, I need to change the image and a paragraph text from the API on the DOM, and I use jquery to do this.

Inside the 'timeupdate' listener, I have a for loop which goes through each marker on the DOM, then it checks to see if the 'currentTime' of the Audio object, is less than the 'timestamp'.

```
 audioObject.addEventListener('timeupdate', () =>
 {
     for (let i = 0; i < $(options.markers).length; i++)
     {
         // If the current time of the audio is greater than the first timestamp second, continue
         if (options.audioObject.currentTime > options.podcastData[i].timestamp)
         {
             options.coverImage.attr('src', options.podcastData[i].image);
             options.theTitle.text(options.podcastData[i].name)
         }
     }

 }, false)
```

Now this works, but it updates the DOM every second, so I see flashes on the Inspector Element until the podcast is finished.

What I need is to update the DOM only once when it has past a marker, but at the moment I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: What other external libraries are you using here? Id's you can do a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I normally try to avoid answers that are just "oh throw library Foo at the problem" -- but in this case you really might want to look at http://popcornjs.org -- it's designed for pretty much exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make two changes:

1. Go through the list in reverse order, and quit once you've hit a match. As it is, you're needlessly setting and resetting the attributes.
2. Set a "seen" attribute on each option once you've displayed it. Don't display it twice.

```js
 for (let i = $(options.markers).length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
     if (options.audioObject.currentTime > options.podcastData[i].timestamp)
     {
         if (! options.podcastData[i].seen)
         {
           options.coverImage.attr('src', options.podcastData[i].image);
           options.theTitle.text(options.podcastData[i].name)
           options.podcastData[i].seen = true
         }

         break
     }
 }
```

Comment: Wow, using the .seen was an excellent idea - Now, when I click on the timeline to go to another time on the audio, I imagine I need to set the podcastData[i].seen to false?

Comment: Yes, if you'll be jumping around you'd want to clear the `seen` values with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're always iterating through the entire list of markers each time the event fires, which means you will always display data from markers that occurred in the past and were previously displayed. In your example, by 29 seconds into your audio file, you will have displayed data from the marker that occurs at 5 seconds at the 5 second interval and *every interval after that*, the marker at 10 seconds at the 10 second interval and *every interval after that* and the marker at 29 seconds once. Every time your event fires, you're literally displaying and overwriting every marker whose `timestamp` fits with every other marker whose `timestamp` fits one after the other.

What if you remove markers from your array after they've been displayed? Once a marker is past and you update the image and title, you won't need to display it again as the audio file progresses, since you already have (and, if you do, you can always restore a cached copy of your array of markers, like, say, if the user rewinds the stream, if that's possible).

```
 audioObject.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
 for (let i = 0; i < $(options.markers).length; i++)
 {
     // If the current time of the audio is greater than the first timestamp second, continue
     if (options.audioObject.currentTime > options.podcastData[i].timestamp)
     {
         options.coverImage.attr('src', options.podcastData[i].image);
         options.theTitle.text(options.podcastData[i].name)

         // *** We've displayed this marker. No need to display it the next
         // time this event fires!
         options.markers = options.markers.splice(i, 1);
     }
 }

 }, false)
```

This way, you're not constantly displaying old markers' data (and then overwriting them with data from other markers, and so on) each time your event fires.

Comment: This is great, gives me a better idea how exactly a loop is working in this particular sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (options.theTitle.text()!=options.podcastData[i].name) options.theTitle.text(options.podcastData[i].name);
```

That should only update the content if the current content is different than the one you want to display. There is similar syntax you can use for the image but I don't want to risk typing it without testing and I am unable to test at the moment.

Comment: The same problem does occur, I think the problem is during the for loop, the "i" variable, goes like this. 

In the beginning, it is fine, it sees that the currentTime is less than the first timestamp, so it loops the # 0.

Then, it sees that the currentTime is now greater than two timestamps, so the "i" variable then gives me,  0, 1 ..0, 1...0, 1,, and so on..and so on....

So the condition doesn't work =/

Comment: What you should do is keep the value of `i` that last satisfied the condition and start the next loop from `i+1`, not from `0`.